# Incompatible types: 'string' and 'Boolean'

Tags: delphi-xe

I have to check for a sound card, so I don't need quality but only one answer yes or no. I used this code:

```
function IsSoundCardInstalled: Boolean;
Begin
   Result := waveOutGetNumDevs > 0;
End;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  ids: TidIpWatch;
  Speed: Double;
  myStringList: TStringList;
begin
  ids := TidIpWatch.Create;
  Speed := GetCPUSpeed;
  ids.Free;

  myStringList:=TStringList.Create;
  myStringList.Add('IP:' + (ids.LocalIP));
  myStringList.Add('CPU: ' + (Tipo_cpu) + ' ' + Format('%f', [Speed]));
  myStringList.Add((IsSoundCardInstalled));
  myStringList.Add('etc.');

  Memo1.Lines.Assign(myStringList);

  myStringList.Free;
end;
```

But the error returns to me:

> [DCC Error] Unit1.pas(138): E2010 Incompatible types: 'string' and 'Boolean'

On the line:

```
myStringList.Add((IsSoundCardInstalled));
```

Comment: You asked the exact same question two days ago. Literally the identical E2010 error! Are you going to ask about E2010 Incompatible types: 'string' and 'Integer' next? Please make more effort to understand the answer to your previous question.

Answer (score 0):

`IsSoundCardInstalled()` returns a `Boolean`, but `myStringList.Add()` expects a `string` instead. You can't assign a `Boolean` as-is to a `string`, you need to use a *conversion* function (just like in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71018437/)), such as [`SysUtils.BoolToStr()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.BoolToStr):

```
uses
  ..., SysUtils;

myStringList.Add(BoolToStr(IsSoundCardInstalled));
```

Or [`SysUtils.TBooleanHelper.ToString()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.SysUtils.TBooleanHelper.ToString) in XE4+:

```
uses
  ..., SysUtils;

myStringList.Add(IsSoundCardInstalled.ToString);
```

---

On a side note: you are freeing the `TIdIPWatch` component before reading its `LocalIP` property, which is *undefined behavior*.

For that matter, you should not be using `TIdIPWatch` in this manner at all.  It is meant for notifying you when the local IP changes, and for maintaining a history of local IP changes over time, but that is not how you have been using it lately. The `TIdIPWatch.LocalIP` property simply reads the global `GStack.LocalAddress` property, that is what you should be using instead:

```
uses
  ..., IdStack;

TIdStack.IncUsage;
try
  myStringList.Add('IP:' + GStack.LocalAddress);
finally
  TIdStack.DecUsage;
end;
```

However, a machine can have multiple local IPs, so you really should use `GStack.GetLocalAddressList()` instead:

```
uses
  ..., IdStack;

var
  myLocalIPList: TIdStackLocalAddressList;
  i: Integer;
begin
  ...
  TIdStack.IncUsage;
  try
    myLocalIPList := TIdStackLocalAddressList.Create;
    try
      GStack.GetLocalAddressList(myLocalIPList);
      for I := 0 to myLocalIPList.Count-1 do
        myStringList.Add('IP:' + myLocalIPList[I].IPAddress);
    finally
      list.Free;
    end;
  finally
    TIdStack.DecUsage;
  end;
  ...
end;
```